# Im trying to get the parallel arrays that I set up to properly compare with items in a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, substring

I pulled in some data from a text file and made them into 4 parallel arrays. One array for a currency code, a currency description, an exchange rate and then an array that holds all of them together. The file im trying to compare to is a list of transaction amounts with currency codes.

My goal is to match the currency code in the array with the code in the file and then do the math to find the value after multiplying the exchange rate by the transaction amount.

Arrays are still a bit of a mystery to me. I understand how to set them up, but actually doing things with the data stored within the array is a bit of a challenge for me still. Would anyone be able to help me do what I'm trying to do? The area I think that's causing the problem I commented with "issue"

The rates file looks like this:

```
CANCanadian Dollar   000001.24
ATSAustrian Shilling 000011.61
GBPBritish Pound     000000.73
```

And the transaction file looks like this:

```
CRC000500.00
ILS000250.00
EUR010000.00
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace CurrencyConversion
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Creating and running the parallel arrays
            int i = 0;
            int x = 0;
            string[] arrayRate = new string[10];
            string[] arrayCode = new string[10];
            string[] arrayDescription = new string[10];
            decimal[] arrayExchange = new decimal[10];

            string strRInputPath = "Rates.txt";
            string strROutputPath = "Report.txt";
            string strRInputLine;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strRInputPath))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strROutputPath))
            {
                while ((strRInputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //Parse Rates
                    string RCurrencyCode = strRInputLine.Substring(0, 3);
                    string CurrencyDescription = strRInputLine.Substring(3, 18);
                    decimal ExchangeRate = Convert.ToDecimal(strRInputLine.Substring(21, 9));

                    arrayRate[i] = strRInputLine;
                    arrayCode[i] = RCurrencyCode;
                    arrayDescription[i] = CurrencyDescription;
                    arrayExchange[i] = ExchangeRate;
                    i++;

                }
                foreach (var value in arrayRate)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(value);
                }
                foreach (var value in arrayCode)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(value);
                }
                foreach (var value in arrayDescription)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(value);
                }
                foreach (var value in arrayExchange)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(value);
                }

            // Comparing text file to the arrays
            
            string strTInputPath = "Trans.txt";
            string strTOutputPath = "Report1.txt";
            string strTInputLine;
            using (StreamReader srt = new StreamReader(strTInputPath))
            using (StreamWriter swt = new StreamWriter(strTOutputPath))


            {
                while ((strTInputLine = srt.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //Parse Trans
                    string TCurrencyCode = strTInputLine.Substring(0, 3);
                    decimal Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(strTInputLine.Substring(3, 9));
                    swt.WriteLine(TCurrencyCode + " " + Amount);
                        
                        foreach (var value in arrayCode)
                        {
                            if (TCurrencyCode == value)
                            {
                                
                                Amount = Amount * arrayExchange[x];
                                sw.WriteLine(arrayExchange.Length);  // < issue 
                                x++;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                   
                }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a few things. I realize now that the WriteLine is just displaying the array length. Before that I would try write lining the amount, but that was just multiplying the rate and transactions in order down the list. It was not properly pairing rates and transactions with matching currency codes.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and give a short sampling of the data in the Rates.txt file? Also, first impression is that you might be trying to do something with arrays where arrays would not be an optimal solution. It sounds as though you want to read **a currency code, a currency description, an exchange rate** and then bundle them all together in a way you can work with the values. It's possible you might get a better answer if you leave the "parallel arrays" part out of the question and focus on the outcome you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I've added the rates.txt and transactions.txt samples to the post. Also, while maybe not ideal, this is for an assignment where I'm told we must use arrays. So I think I'm going to have to stick to that method.

Comment: Thx for those updates. Knowing that the use of arrays is a requirement is helpful.

Comment: OK so this has provided enough info for me to reproduce and run your code up to where you have marked `// issue`. Your observation is correct, it's writing the array length and that's not what you want. So, putting aside what _is_ happening in each loop iteration, please talk me through what _should be_ happening in each iteration. What is your intended outcome?

Comment: there is no actual question here. What are you asking?

Comment: I did ask a question, but I'll clarify. At the //issue I would like that code to say something along the lines of: look at the line in the transactions.text (the part stored in TCurrencyCode) and match it with the same currency code in arrayCode. Where it finds matching currency codes, take the transaction at that same line in transactions.text and multiply it with the value stored in arrayExchange. I assume by setting up parallel arrays, the same index for the code in arrayCode should match the index for the exchange rate in arrayExchange.   Does that make sense?

Comment: It _does_ make sense. So _much_ sense that one might wonder about the choice of a `foreach`. Why not use a `for-next` with the index values?

Comment: I'm not opposed to using a different looping method. foreach is just what I was able to come up with when researching how to get this done. I am not familiar with for-next and haven't stumbled across it in my research for this. Would you be able to give me an example of how that may work with my code?

Comment: I'll bet if you give it a go you can do it :)

Comment: I will certainly try! Im new to the site, so if I get stuck and I come back to this post and comment again will I be able to get more help? Either from you or another user?

Comment: Yes! Of course. All we ask is that you make as good an effort as you can to solve it on you own (and for most of us that starts with searching on SO and on the interwebs for existing solutions).

Comment: I totally understand that. I will look into your suggestions and hopefully I wont have to come back :) Thank you a ton!

Comment: Microsoft documentation: [Iteration Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements) see `for`.